# Play Market - система подписок для игры

Tags: android, python, kivy, playmarket

Создаю андроид игру на kivy, хочу выложить ее в play market.
Мне нужно реализовать систему подписок для игры, и я не знаю как лучше ее сделать?
Есть ли в самом Play Market такая возможность?
Ну то есть, API подписок или документация?

Comment: такая система есть и она легко находится by Google